# SceneKit: export scene as STL file for 3D printing?

Tags: 3d, scenekit

How can you export a SceneKit scene as a STL file (for 3D printing)?

The [write](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnscene/1523577-write) function from `SCNScene` does not appear to support the STL format.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `SCNScene`'s `write(to:options:delegate:progressHandler:)`.

While the online documentation only mentions Collada and SceneKit file formats, the header documentation states that:

> macOS 10.10 and lower only supports exporting to .dae files.
>
> Starting iOS 10 exporting supports .scn as well as all file formats supported by Model I/O.
>
> Starting macOS 10.11 exporting supports .dae, .scn as well as file all formats supported by Model I/O.

Answer (score 1):

The `export` function in ModelIO (MDLAsset) appears to support STL, but I've never tried it myself.

[MDLAsset:export()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/modelio/mdlasset/1391036-export)

Comment: Thanks Hal! When you say `export` function, which one do you mean? Searching the class docs for Model I/O does not turn up an export function: https://developer.apple.com/reference/modelio.