# Unable to export SceneKit scene as .stl file

Tags: ios, swift, stl, scenekit

I have tried using both SCNScene's `write(to:options:delegate:progressHandler:)` and initializing an MDLAsset with the SCNScene and exporting as a "**.stl**" file. Both resulted in the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'

Despite the MDLAsset documentation stating that .stl is a supported filetype, the canExportFileExtension("**.stl**") returns false.

Additionally, I have not created an array, nor have I explicitly checked an element of any array in the line that causes the crash, so I assume the error stems from somewhere in the process of exporting a scene to a .stl file.

Has anybody found a solution to this error? I have tried both suggestions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713365/scenekit-export-scene-as-stl-file-for-3d-printing), to no avail.

Comment: That crash happened inside a method of MDLAsset. In the debug navigator you can go down the list to see from which line of your code this was called.

Comment: @KugelnMMXVI I know which line of code is causing the issue. Also, when using SCNScene's write method, I am not using MDLAsset. SCNScene can export as a .dae file, however I need to export the textures from the scene as well. Both methods use the same block of assembly code, and that block causes the crash. However, I am not proficient enough in assembly to make heads or tails of what's happening. Should I copy the assembly code here?

Comment: No, that would not help at all. What is returned by 'canExportFileExtension("stl")' (without the point)?

Comment: @KugelnMMXVI Okay, it returns true without the point, that's a good start, thanks! However, I'm still unable to initialize the MDLAsset with a SCNScene, or export directly from the SCNScene using the write method. Should I provide the stack traces for both errors?

Comment: That could give a clue.